# detectMultiScale function cannot be found in cv2?

Tags: python, opencv

First time posting.

I'm currently trying to use opencv2 in python using virtual studio on M1 macbook air, but for some reason I cannot use the detectMultiScale function? I have completely uninstalled everything and reinstalled everything to no avail. `error: (-215) !empty() in function detectMultiScale`

For instance:
**grayscaled_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)**

**face_coordinates = trained_face_data.detectMultiScale(grayscaled_img)**

gets me

```
    face_coordinates = trained_face_data.detectMultiScale(grayscaled_img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) /private/var/folders/nz/vv4_9tw56nv9k3tkvyszvwg80000gn/T/pip-req-build-39p1qqfs/opencv/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'detectMultiScale'
```

Also, I am completely new with using python, so a quick question I have is whether I need to create a virtual environment, activate it, and then pip download opencv2 there? I tried downloading cv2 into just my python file's terminal, but I'm unable to import cv2 there. I'm thinking it might be because the file paths are different? But I have no idea how to use pip installer to a certain file path. I can only import cv2 after installing cv2 inside a venv.

Please advise, thank you!

Before asking this question I've tried :

```py
import cv2

#trained face data import
trained_face_data = cv2.CascadeClassifier('frontfacedetector.xml')

#import my face
img = cv2.imread('Aaron_Prof_Pic.jpg')

#change to grayscale
grayscaled_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#detecting faces
face_coordinates = trained_face_data.detectMultiScale(grayscaled_img)

cv2.imshow('why isnt this working', grayscaled_img)
cv2.waitKey()

print("Code completed")
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that the `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml` isn't present in the same directory as of the code or either it's corrupted.

If it's there in the same directory  then try using

```py
trained_face_data = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades+"haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
```

The final code should look somewhat like :

```py
import cv2
trained_face_data = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades+"haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
img = cv2.imread('Aaron_Prof_Pic.jpg')
imgGray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = trained_face_data.detectMultiScale(imgGray)
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0,255,0), 2) 
cv2.imshow("Face detector", img)
key_press = cv2.waitKey(1)
if key_press == 32: #The ascii code for spacebar
    quit()#quits the programme when spacebar is hit
```

Comment: Sorry, I typed it wrong, I actually have the . in the real code. the problem is that detectMultiScale isn't detected as a function

Comment: this means either the haarcascade file isn't in the same folder or either it's corrupted

Comment: Have you downloaded the `.xml` from the official github repositry of `cv2`?
If yes then have a look at my ans

Comment: Try running the final code(that I've mentioned in my answer) on your IDE and see if that works

Comment: that worked! What did you do? Im sorry, I dont understand the concept between your code vs my code and I would like to learn so that I can improve my skills. Thanks!

Comment: Just replaced cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_data.xml") to 
cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascade + "haarcascade_frontal_face_data.xml")

Comment: The `.xml` is located in the location cv2/data/haarcascades have a look at this reposity of  cv2 https://github.com/opencv/opencv and follow the same location as I mentioned

Comment: Also have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers